# JavaScript Promises: Chaining promise confusion

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I've been playing with Promises and the chaining in the following example doesn't return the expected result.
The `getHeroChain()` function works as expected, but the `getHeroUnChain()` function doesn't. In both cases, the execution order is as expected, but, in `getHeroUnChain()`, that last `then` function doesn't return the expected value (the `HEROES` array).

```
var HEROES = [{
    id: 11,
    name: 'Mr. Nice'
}, {
    id: 12,
    name: 'Narco'
}, ];

function getHeros() {
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES); // resolved promise
}

function getHerosSlowlyChained() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(" 1) inside setTimeout");
            resolve(2);
        }, 2000);

    }).then(function(value) {

        console.log(" 2) setTimeout resolved");
        console.log(" 2) inside 1st 'then' with value : " + value);
        return getHeros(); //return promise
    });
}

function getHerosSlowlyUnchained() { //not directly chained
    var mainPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(" 1) inside setTimeout");
            resolve(2);
        }, 2000);
    });

    mainPromise.then(function(value) {

        console.log(" 2) setTimeout resolved");
        console.log(" 2) inside 1st 'then' with value : " + value);
        return getHeros(); //return promise

    });

    return mainPromise;
}

//Chained
function getHeroChain() {

    var heroPromise = getHerosSlowlyChained();

    heroPromise.then(function(heroes) {
        console.log(" 3) inside final 'then' with heroes :");
        console.log(heroes);
    });

}
//Un-Chained
function getHeroUnChain() {

    var heroPromise = getHerosSlowlyUnchained();

    heroPromise.then(function(heroes) {
        console.log(" 3) inside final 'then' with heroes :");
        console.log(heroes);
    });

}

//getHeroChain();
getHeroUnChain();
```

Output of `getHeroChain()`:

> 1) inside setTimeout
>   2) setTimeout resolved
>   2) inside 1st 'then' with value : 2
>   3) inside final 'then' with heroes : [Object, Object]

Output of `getHeroUnChain()`:

> 1) inside setTimeout
>   2) setTimeout resolved
>   2) inside 1st 'then' with value : 2
>   3) inside final 'then' with heroes : 2

JSBIN link : https://jsbin.com/pivoyuyawu/edit?js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you return `mainPromise` in `getHerosSlowlyUnchained`. Every call to `then` or similar methods returns a **new** promise in the chain.

In `getHeroChain`, your chain is: `setTimeout` -> `setTimeout resolved`-> `final then`.

In `getHeroUnChain` your chain is: `setTimeout` -> [`setTimeout resolved`, `final then`].

Note that in the second example, both `setTimeout resolved` and `final then` are after `setTimeout`. This means that both are given `2`.

To fix, either do

```
return mainPromise.then(function(value) {

    console.log(" 2) setTimeout resolved");
    console.log(" 2) inside 1st 'then' with value : " + value);
    return getHeros(); //return promise

});
```

or

```
mainPromise = mainPromise.then(function(value) {

    console.log(" 2) setTimeout resolved");
    console.log(" 2) inside 1st 'then' with value : " + value);
    return getHeros(); //return promise

});
return mainPromise;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping and the nice detailed explanation. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**`.then()` always generate a new promise, so in your UnChained function, you should return the new promise, instead of the old mainPromise**

```
function getHerosSlowlyUnchained() { //not directly chained
    var mainPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(" 1) inside setTimeout");
            resolve(2);
        }, 2000);
    });

    // this will generate a new promise, you should return the new one
    // instead of the old mainPromise
    mainPromise.then(function(value) {

        console.log(" 2) setTimeout resolved");
        console.log(" 2) inside 1st 'then' with value : " + value);
        return getHeros(); //return promise

    });

    return mainPromise;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out. :)